# Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

*Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token [...] (through reference chain: [...].model.User["ethnicities"])*

I have a user object with a property `ethnicities`.

From what I can tell the error is because the json "type" doesn't match the property type but in my case both are String arrays.

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I can't figure out what `VALUE_STRING` represents in the parsing.

Server-side is using Loopback and the ethnicities property is defined as such:

`"ethnicities": [
      ""
    ]`

Android client is using Jackson to map the json to the pojo and vice versa.  Ethnicities in pojo looks like this:

```
private String[] ethnicities;
public String[] getEthnicities() {return ethnicities;}
public void setEthnicities(String[] ethnicities) {this.ethnicities = ethnicities;}
```

The mapping to json:

```
try {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonUserObject = mapper.writeValueAsString(user);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException converting user object to JSON");
}
```

and the mapping from json:

```
try {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    user = mapper.readValue(userObjectJSON, User.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException converting JSON to user object");
}
```

Here's some examples of incoming json:

```
"ethnicities": [
      "Asian",
      "American Indian",
      "Hispanic"
    ]

"ethnicities": [
  "Caucasian"
]

"ethnicities": null
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try setting this flag to `ObjectMapper` :

```
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

Comment: No, I had seen that and tried it and it didn't work.  I don't have `DeserializationFeature` though, I access it through `DeserializationConfig.Feature` and it doesn't prevent the error.

Answer (score 0):

Is that the whole JSON you're handling?

I was facing a similar problem today. It seems, it is not possible to deserialize a JSON-Array to a Java String[] or List when the property to serialize is the JSON root property.

In the end I wrapped the value in another object. In your case it may look like:

```
"user": {
  "ethnicities": [
    "Asian",
    "American Indian",
    "Hispanic",
  ]
}
```

Maybe it is just a configuration problem - but I couldn't figure out, how to deal with it yet without wrapping the Array.

Hope, that helps.
Daniel